# My google sheets QUERY is showing numbers as date code

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets QUERY like this.. =QUERY(Orders!$A:H, "SELECT D, E, F WHERE NOT H LIKE '%Canceled%'")

But the formula is showing me the numbers as a date code.

I want the formula to be exactly the way it is on the sheet i am using the query from.

I have attached a sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17kTTLlEXPdMgf7Ye9SeQoctwvGR_Zhyic3-XWHL-XWs/edit#gid=0

Comment: Please check the shared spreadsheet's content.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes i dont see any edits on the sheet..

Comment: I really don't understand how the query you posted on the question has any to do with the actual data of your sample spreadsheet. Can you [edit] and add the current and expected result?

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes I've added the data

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes  My original sheet has sensitiver data, is there a way to add a function/formula to change the info to number from date?

Comment: Could you share a copy data but erase the other columns that have sensitive data? It's strange that it's taking it that way, you may probably have some formatting issues in the original data

Comment: I added the data to Sheet2

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to add a function/formula to change the info to number from date?

you can try forced format: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#format

```
format F '0'
```

or instead of `0` try `#` or `@`

Comment: how do i add that to my formula?

Comment: @Jerry try: `=QUERY(Orders!$A:H, "SELECT D, E, F WHERE NOT H LIKE '%Canceled%' format F '0'")`